# Decoding multi-level JSON into structs with Swift 4 is nil

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

this is the object data server feedback,I plan to decoder it to my struct with swift4.0 JSONDecoder,but I meet some problem, the result always nil :

```
{
"code":"000000",
"isAutoRequest":0,
"message":"wwwwwww",
"ruleList":[
    {
        "rateList":[{
                "rate":"2.1",
                "rateCode":1,
                "rateName":1
            },{
                "rate":"2.1",
                "rateCode":2,
                "rateName":2
            },{
                "rate":"2.1",
                "rateCode":3,
                "rateName":3
            }],
        "ruleCode": "sanjundaxiao",
        "ruleName": "eeeeee",
        "sort": "07"
    },
    {
        "rateList":[{
                "rate": "185",
                "rateCode": 111,
                "rateName": 111
            },{
                "rate": "185",
                "rateCode": 222,
                "rateName": 222
            }],
        "ruleCode": "code2",
        "ruleName": "eeeqqqqq",
        "sort": "08"
    }]
```

}

this is my struct for decoder the server data:

```
struct GroupRateModel:Codable {
    var isAutoRequest:String?
    var ruleList:[RuleRateList]?
    var code:String?
    var message:String?
}

struct RuleRateList:Codable {
    var rateList:[RateList]?
    var ruleCode:String?
    var ruleName:String?
    var sort:String?
}

struct RateList:Codable {
    var rate:String?
    var rateCode:String?
    var rateName:String?
}
```

I use the follow code to decoder the data, but the result(dataModel is nil) is always nil, I don't know where is wrong, I am a new guy for swift, hope somebody can show me the right way, thank you!

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 let resultData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultDic, options: [])
 if let data = resultData{
    let dataModel = try? decoder.decode(GroupRateModel.self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: As posted, neither `code` nor `isAutoRequest` are `String`s.  *edit* I see that you posted the debug output of an `NSDictionary`.  Please post the raw JSON.

Comment: add catch block and print the error

Comment: Just add Json in question not  debug output

Comment: I already update the json

Comment: Remove **all** question marks especially the `try?` in the `decoder` line and read the error message. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @vadian,thank you, like you said, I find the way to solve the problem!